# How to implement this method chaining

Tags: ruby

In one of the interview, they asked me to write code for

```
car1 = Car.make("Honda").model("Civic").year("2009")
car2 = Car.make("Toyota").model("Camry").year("2009")


car1.to_s --> Honda Civic 2009
car2.to_s --> Toyota Camry 2009
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a so-called [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface). You can implement it by returning `self` from the methods:

```
class Car
  def make(value)
    @make = value
    self
  end

  def model(value)
    @model = value
    self
  end

  def year(value)
    @year = value
    self
  end

  def to_s
    [@make, @model, @year].compact.join(' ')
  end
end


puts Car.new.make("Honda").model("Civic").year("2009")
# Honda Civic 2009
```

Note that I had to call `new` in the beginning because `make`, `model` and `year` are instance methods.

To omit `new` (as shown in your example), you can provide class methods with the same names that wrap the `new` call and delegate to their respective instance counterparts:

```
class Car
  def self.make(value)
    new.make(value)
  end

  def self.model(value)
    new.model(value)
  end

  # and so on
end

puts Car.make("Honda").model("Civic").year("2009")
# Honda Civic 2009
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. Here is one.

```
module Car
  @str = ''

  def self.make(car_name)
    @str = car_name + ' '
    self
  end

  def self.model(model_name)
    @str += model_name + ' '
    self
  end

  def self.year(year)
    @str + year
  end
end
```

```
Car.make("Honda").model("Civic").year("2009").to_s
  #=> Honda Civic 2009
```

```
Car.make("BMW").model("i3").year("2015").to_s
  #=> BMW i3 2015
```

---

One could alternatively replace `Car::year` with

```
def self.year(year)
  @str += year
end
```

and add

```
def self.to_s
  @str
end
```

Comment: But what about `car1` and `car2`? I don’t have a computer right now, but it seems as if you can only have one car at a time with the class-method only approach.

Comment: @Stefan, I don't understand your point. The question says nothing about the need for instances or even of a class. I'm merely producing the desired behavior.

Comment: The question doesn’t say anything about instances explicitly. But it shows two objects `car1` and `car2` that behave independently. To me, they look like instances.